# Streaming strings into a boost::fusion::vector doesn't work?

Tags: c++, boost, tuples, boost-fusion, boost-tuples

I'd like to initialize a fusion::vector by streaming from std::cin. It seems this isn't possible as the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/sequence/operator/i_o.html) says:

*...extracting Sequence(s) with std::string or C-style string elements does not generally work, since the streamed Sequence representation may not be unambiguously parseable*

This question might have been asked before but I'd like to get to the bottom of what a "parse-able string" might look like.

Her's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/fusion/sequence/io.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/assert.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace boost::fusion;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
void main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("42,aaa,bbb");
    vector<int, std::string, std::string> v;
    iss >> tuple_open("") >> tuple_close("") >>tuple_delimiter(",");
    iss>>v;
    assert(get<1>(v) == std::string("aaa,bbb"));
    cout << v << endl;
    cout << "element 0: " << get<0>(v) << endl;
    cout << "element 1: " << get<1>(v) << endl;
    cout << "element 2: " << get<2>(v) << endl;
}
```

output:

```
(42 aaa,bbb )
element 0: 42
element 1: aaa,bbb
element 2:
```

How can I get the fusion io operator ">>" to work nicely with std::string?